# How to wire this back up?

Tags: electrical, wire, fans

I was trying to replace my ceiling fan and well of course I didn't take a picture of how the wiring was before I tore it apart so I'm trying to figure out how to put it back together so everything works.  The only thing not in the pic is the fan/light so if you could also let me know where those two wires would go as well would help.

This is what I've figured out:

- yellow circle has the power
- red circle is the other bedroom
- blue circle is the switch
- green circle is the outlet in the room.

[image: Fan wiring]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Remember to take pictures in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you will want to connect the white wires from the yellow, red, green, and the fixture.  Connect all the black wires together except the fixture.

Now the only two wires you have left are the white wire from the switch and the black wire of the fixture.  The white wire will be the "switched hot" and needs to be identified by wrapping a strip of black tape around it.  You don't need to cover up all the white, you just need to have an obvious band of black to mark that wire as hot.

Connect that switched hot white wire to the black wire of the fixture and everything should work fine.  Note that the larger bundles of wires will need to use larger wire nuts (typically red).  Don't try to force more wires into a small yellow wire nut.

Also, I hope the zip ties in the back of that box are not holding the box in place.  The box shouldn't wiggle and should be very securely mounted with strong screws if it's going to hold a fan.

Comment: If there's a blue wire in the fan, it's for the light and should be hooked up to the black wire from the fan and the switched hot white wire with the black tape wrapped around it.+

Comment: I disagree.  This being a "switch leg" circuit, I thought it was convention that the WHITE wire be unswitched and code-taped black.  Then the black wire coming back to the fixture box would be switched, making it obvious that the black wire is intended to be connected to the fixture.  BTW, this is something I learned here from one of the big-3.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, I don't really know if there is a standard...  The instructions were simpler to say "tie all the black wires together", so that's what I went with.  I'm happy to be corrected, but this is a 60yr old install...

Comment: Yeah, I get that as well! I was actually thinking the same thing as you suggested, but didn't want to recommend it since it's not the convention.   I was surprised to learn that, but when I thought about it, it made sense.  It would be more complicated to say "connect the white wire from the switch leg to the hots and code tape it black...etc.etc.etc, but that is the convention.  Nowadays it's required to run /3 if ppl are still stubborn enough to do switch legs.

Comment: George is correct. You must use white for always-hot if you're not using it for neutral.